# Problem executing command "flutter build appbundle"

Tags: android, flutter, release

Im with a problem in execute command "flutter build appbundle".

I placed all configuration in archive build.gradle,modifiquei para todas as versões as dependências "google-services" e "build.gradle", nenhuma funcionou.

I also tested it on a new project, with no dependencies and it didn't work either.

I think it's some version mismatch.

Below are my settings.

[image]

Dependencies Version:

```
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
```

Key Properties:

```
storePassword=password
keyPassword=password
keyAlias=key
storeFile=C:\users\victo\key.jks
```

build.gradle

```
   def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
   keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile)) //line 32
   }
...
signingConfigs {
   release {
       keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
       keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
       storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : 
       null
       storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
   }
}
buildTypes {
   release {
       signingConfig signingConfigs.release
   }
}
```

Comment: since you are on windows make sure your `/` are forward slashes anywhere  you are pointing flutter to a local path.  also use correct dir, `=C:\users\victo\key.jks` from the image the path to your key seems longer.. put it in the android/app folder and the ref it as `storeFile file("mykey")`

Comment: I believe that it is not a routing problem, because before there was a problem with the path and the error was different, and I managed to correct it that way, placing this path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was me, alias name was incorrect!!!